# How to determine if VFPOLEDB provider is installed/registered?

Tags: c#, oledb, provider

I need to check in my program if the VFPOLEDB provider is installed/registered?  I want to show a message and tell the user to download and install the provider. How do I check it in C#?

Answer (score 9):

As suggested here: [How to check if an OLEDB driver is installed on the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113860/how-to-check-if-an-oledb-driver-is-installed-on-the-system) you can look for VFPOLEDB's key in the Registry. Open up `regedit` and search for VFPOLEDB, you'll find it in several places; You're interested in the one over here:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{50BAEECA-ED25-11D2-B97B-000000000000}\1.0\0\win32
```

So we know VFPOLEDB should be registered over here:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{50BAEECA-ED25-11D2-B97B-000000000000}
```

We can test if it's there using this C# expression:

```
(Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("TypeLib\\{50BAEECA-ED25-11D2-B97B-000000000000}") != null)
```

Or we can wrap it up in a nice static class for easy reuse:

```
public static class CheckVfpOleDb
{
    public static bool IsInstalled()
    {
        return Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("TypeLib\\{50BAEECA-ED25-11D2-B97B-000000000000}") != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice solution, but don't forget to close your subkey in case there is some exception.